# What does a conditional check on undefined var do?

Tags: javascript

I have some weird inconsistent bug in my code that's very hard to reproduce. It shows up but if I run the same sequence again, it goes away. If I try to debug it, it goes away.

Anyways, I'm wondering if the following could be the culprit
Suppose I have the following code

```
var myBoolean; // undefined
if( !myBoolean ) {
  doX();
} else {
  doY();
}
```

Question is, in the above code, will it run doX() or doY()?

When I test it, it seems to run doX(), but I know that there's a more proper way of checking for undefined.

```
if( typeof myBoolean == 'undefined' || !myBoolean ) { ...
```

So my question is, could the improper way of checking myBoolean be causing indeterminism in my code? It's just that I would have to make this code change in a lot of places and I just want to know if this is the issue before doing anything.

Comment: So the title would better be something along *How do I test for and only for undefined?*

Comment: You don't even need to check the type of the variable to know if it's `undefined`, just check it's value: `if (myBoolean === undefined) { ...`

Comment: This is obviously an over-simplification of my code. In the actual code, myBoolean can be undefined, true, or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `!myBoolean` will **always** be true when `myBoolean` is `undefined`. However, it will *also* be true when it's `0`, `""`, `false`, `NaN`, or `null`.

Whether that's OK or not depends on the situation in your program. The sample code you wrote is clearly pointless; since `myBoolean` will definitely be `undefined` in that `if` statement, the `if` can be eliminated completely. In a real situation, you may know that a variable or object property will be either `undefined` or an object reference.

A lot of people code defensively as a practice, so such a programmer would be likely to include a more explicit test. *Most* of the time, it's true that the values `null` and `undefined` have the same essential meaning in typical coding situations, so if that's the case then it's safe to write

```
if (myBoolean == null)
```

The `==` comparison will be true only when `myBoolean` is either `undefined` or `null`, and not in any other situations. In other words,

```
if (myBoolean == null)
```

is effectively the same as

```
if (myBoolean === undefined || myBoolean === null)
```

You may use whichever you prefer of course :)

Comment: Just curious, why the type coercion `myBoolean == null` instead of   triple equals?

Comment: @ВидулПетров because when one operand to `==` is `null`, the `==` operand will return `true` if the other operand is either `undefined` or `null`. I'll add a short explanation to the answer.

Comment: I know, just wondering why the concise type coercion instead of `myBoolean === null || myBoolean === undefined`?

Comment: @ВидулПетров because it's shorter! You can use the `===` version if you prefer, or course.

Comment: No more questions. Case dismissed.